# Symfony local web server with domain proxy inconsistent behavior

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, localhost

I cannot seem to get consistent results with the Symfony local webserver using custom domains.

I initially set the proxy up according to the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#local-domain-names) and it initially worked quite well. However on subsequent returns to working on the project it will most of the time fail to work, and I cannot seem to find the right sequence of steps to take in order to make the local server work with the proxy domains.

I understand that others have had issues with Chrome proxy settings and I've followed the steps to omit that to no avail.

I am running Symfony 5.3.7 for this project, locally on MacOS Big Sur 11.6.  This morning returning to the project I have tried the following to no avail...

- Stop and restart the proxy `symfony proxy:stop` & `symfony proxy:start`
- Stop and restart the local server: `symfony server:stop` & `symfony server:start -d`
- Flush the MacOS DNS cache
- Clear the Chrome DNS cache
- Remove bad proxies from Chrome
- Reapply proxy settings in Chrome
- Verified that the proxy PAC file is in place in the networks settings
- Verified that automatic proxy configuration is checked in the network settings
- Cleared all browsing data in Chrome
- Restarted Chrome

I have tried various combinations of all these steps.

I've removed and reattached the proxy domains with the Symfony CLI.

I've tried other browsers including Safari and Firefox.

When I start the server, I can see that the domains are attached, or when I navigate to http://localhost:7080 I can see they are attached and 'running'.

When I visit the local domains I get the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached
Check if there is a typo in (domain).wip.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

The only way I can visit the local site is thru the local host IP and the port that is assigned when I start the Symfony Server.

Comment: sometimes I need to close/reopen my browser, then the DNS error goes away.

Comment: @Mcsky thank you. As I mentioned above I have tried that.

Comment: Started experiencing exactly the same problem today on a fresh install of Linux Mint 21.1 with Symfony CLI 5.4.21. Always worked fine for me and still working now on Linux Mint 20.3 with Symfony CLI 5.4.8. Did you find an answer @RobertWade? I'll share mine if/when I fix it.

Comment: @Grease I gave up on Symfony server awhile back and started using Laravel Valet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your website in incognito mode (so that all plugins get disabled). For me, I had a plugin for TunnelBear VPN. After I disabled the plugin, it started to work.